# Error: Non-invocable member 'Vector2' cannot be used like a method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to do Vector2(-1, 0) instead of Vector2.left but it gives this error:

```
Non-invocable member 'Vector2' cannot be used like a method
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you do `new Vector2(-1, 0)` ?

Comment: Not familiar with Unity, but from the error message it sounds like `Vector2` is a property.

Comment: @Tim Interesting, `member` makes it sound that way but it's actually a `struct`.

Answer (score 4):

`Vector2.Left` is equal to `new Vector2(-1,0)`; , not `Vector2(-1, 0)` :)

Answer (score 3):

I think this happens because you use syntax like this:

```
Vector2 vec;
//assign new value
vec = Vector2(-1,0);
```

This  is not gonna work because compiler thinks that you are using method called Vector2() which doesn't exist and it is not correct because you should create a new object and then assign its value to vec variable. For example:

```
Vector2 vec;
//assign new value
vec = new Vector2(-1,0); //you create a new Vector2 and assign its value to vec
```

or, the better way will be to store your Vector2(-1,0) in an individual variable. Like this:

```
Vector2 vec, leftVec;

leftVec = new Vector2(-1,0);
//assign new value
vec = leftVec;
```

This way you may change your varialble's value without creating a new object every time.