# Why is Vector3 non-invocable here and what can I do instead?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity I'm trying to update a y coordinate like this:

```
if (ballPos.position.y > aiPos.position.y)
    {
        transform.position += Vector3 (0.0f, 1.0f, 0f);
    }
```

I'm getting the error that `Vector3` is a non-invocable method what can I do to change the position effectively?

Comment: The code you show is valid in UnityScript, as it does not require the new keyword. In C#, you need the new.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Non-invocable member 'Vector2' cannot be used like a method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32997907/error-non-invocable-member-vector2-cannot-be-used-like-a-method)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you need a constructor call there:

```
transform.position += new Vector3 (0.0f, 1.0f, 0f);
```

Of course, since [0,1,0] is so common it has a name: you can also use

```
transform.position += Vector3.up;
```

Comment: If possible please don't answer duplicates. There is a huge amount of clutter in the Unity3D tag.  This particular question has been asked 100s of times.

Comment: @JoeBlow, that might be obvious to someone very active in the Unity3D tag, but the duplication wasn't easily discoverable to me - and perhaps not easily discoverable to others as well, if it's that heavily duplicated.  I just took it as a random C# question.

Comment: Sure, I'm just mentioning to anyone who'll listen, the incredible Unity3D clutter building up on here; it's worth bearing in mind, I think.  Next step is answers.unity3d.com  :/